# Meteor + Mongo Average Count

Tags: javascript, mongodb, algorithm, math, meteor

Let's say I have a document like this

```
{
    "_id" : "PQ8GUYYB7IERPNE9NX-CombQQD7F",
    "combId" : 5,
    "alignToOffer" : true,
    "product" : "TwBuYJZquKeKTmtwr",
    "price" : 85,
}
```

now i want to get average of each combination of same product to align (if it's checked to align) so am using the meteor observe handle to do this. and get aggregated average price values it on every changes for related documents

```
Offers.find({}).observe({
   changed: function(offer, fields) {

      var result = Offers.aggregate(
          [
             {
                $match:
                {
                   product: offer.product,
                   status: true,
                   combId: Number(offer.combId)
                }
             },
             {
                $group:
                {
                   _id: "$product",
                   priceAlign: { $avg: "$price" },
                   minPrice: { $min: "$price" }
                }
             }
          ]
      );

      if ( result.length ){
         var averageValue = parseFloat(Math.round(result[0].priceAlign * 100) / 100).toFixed(2),
         bestOffer = parseFloat(Math.round(result[0].minPrice * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
         var updateValues = { $set: {
            avgOffer: averageValue,
            bestOffer: bestOffer
         }};

         var updatePrice = { $set: {
            price : averageValue
         }};

         Offers.update({
            product: offer.product,
            combId: offer.combId,
            status: true
         }, updateValues, {multi: true});

         Offers.update({
            product: offer.product,
            combId: offer.combId,
            alignToOffer: true,
            status: true
         }, updatePrice, {multi: true});
      }
   }
});
```

it's works perfectly, there is the REAL Issue to save average price. to conclude i have three documents for same product, two of them aligned (align to offer key checked) and one is not, now when I changed the fixed value doc price(which is not aligned) then the other two will save with `+1` or `-1` (with decimal places) not the same price i.e if i save the fixed price with `96` the other one will have the price of `95.99999999999996` or `96.00000000000001` not `96`. I need here a whole number but when i remove decimal values with any method of vanilla JS. e.g `toFixed()` it will give me  1 less or  1 more value. I bumping my head on PC since night. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**last change yet give me `96.01` or `95.99`**

Comment: It's really not clear what your question is. Also calling methods from inside a publication seems very slow and confusing to debug. You can probably separate your observer from your publication since the publication will automatically update whenever you update an `Offers` document. Finally, you pass `obj` to your publication but don't use it before you override it in a `.forEach()` callback.

Comment: (1) if you're doing all this on the server you shouldn't need a method call at all so you could make your code synchronous/simpler. (2) When an Offer changes and your observer fires you change another offer which results in the observer firing again, cascading the change. (3) can you post the call of your `avgCombination` method? (4) Even though you're iterating across offers with a `.forEach()` the params to the method call don't change each time as they are set earlier (5) you can update multiple records at the same time with `$multi: true` in your `.update()` if you're on the server.

Comment: @MichelFloyd see my updated server code...!

Comment: Why are you doing `toFixed(2)` instead of `toFixed(0)` if you want an integer result? Also you are saving your prices as strings instead of numbers, are you sure that's what you intended? `toFixed()` results in a string, not a number.

Comment: yup that's the real question with me if i save with `toFixed(0)` it give +1 or -1 value that's why i do `parseFloat(Math.round(result[0].minPrice * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);` but still not same number

Comment: Do you mean that `averageValue` would be `95.99999999999996` or `96.00000000000001`, or that `averageValue` is `96` but the saved values are `95.99999999999996` or `96.00000000000001`.

Another thing you might be able to do is set `averageValue` to `result[0].priceAlign` (with no rouding) and round on the client.

Comment: @Guig yes i mean the average value comes as `95.99999999999996` or `96.00000000000001`. I already did that with result[0].price and also tried rounding on client too. but i don't want display rounded values only on client. I need exact values saved in db as well

Comment: Don't save numeric values as strings. That's just terrible practice. You can render them as strings later in the client but don't put them in mongo that way. Your approach of using an observer is going to cause the observer to run multiple times. Put a `console.log(averageValue)` in there to see how your code is firing and what the value is at every step.

Comment: Thanks @MichelFloyd I updated as you suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to put extra logic for calculatin avg. 
just follow  below step OR use mongoDB `$avg` operator.

1) In your case first you get all document that have `alignToOffer: false`.

2) After calculating it's average using `aggregation`. 
OR manually calculate like below.

3) Set in those document that `alignToOffer: true` simple.

1)

`let result = Offers.find({
         product: offer.product,
         status: true,
         alignToOffer: false,
         combId: Number(offer.combId)
 }).fetch();  //fetch for meteor.`

2)

`// if get only one document then set it's price no need to calculate avg
let avg = result.length > 1 ?
result.map(obj => obj.price).reduce((o,n) => o + n) / result.length :
result[0].price;`

3)

`Offers.update({
         product: offer.product,
         alignToOffer: true,
         status: true,
         combId: Number(offer.combId)
}, {$set:{ price : Number(avg) }}, { multi: true });`

Comment: Excellent , although I made some changes but only calculating the average for offers which `alignToOffer: false` is solved the issue, Thanks for providing out of the Box solution.